# ImportError: cannot import name 'KernelProvisionerBase' from 'jupyter_client.provisioning'

Tags: python

Very messy tonight. It was working fine before until I tried to upgrade tensorflow to 2.6. it failed, then all other packages also broke. for example, I cannot launch jupypter notebook. I did try to upgrade it by using conda update jupyter. Thanks for your help.

```
(forecast) C:\Python_Sync\ML timeseries>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\forecast\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\forecast\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 78, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager, AsyncMappingKernelManager
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\forecast\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import Session
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\forecast\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .manager import AsyncKernelManager  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\forecast\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .provisioning import KernelProvisionerBase
ImportError: cannot import name 'KernelProvisionerBase' from 'jupyter_client.provisioning' (unknown location)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, i ended up solving this after:

```
conda update --all
```